# PostgreSQL: built-in function to remove substring starting with certain pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, built-in

In my table I have a `col_A` like below:

```
col_A
-----------------------------------
Dog_qq123r_sdf
Cat_old_qq34569er
Bird_tweet_A_qqikdf0_qq_sdfad
Cow_moo_moo_qq1_qq2_qq3
```

I would like to create a derived column `derived_col_A` from `col_A`. The rule is `'remove everything starting from first _qq'`

```
col_A                            derived_col_A
------------------------------------------------
Dog_qq123r_sdf                      Dog
Cat_old_qq34569er                   Cat_old
Bird_tweet_A_qqikdf0_qq_sdfad       Bird_tweet_A
Cow_moo_moo_qq1_qq2_qq3             Cow_moo_moo
```

Is there a built-in function that can transform `col_A` to `derived_col_A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `regexp_replace()` to handle this:

```
 SELECT regexp_replace(Col_A, '_qq.*$',NULL) from your_table;
```

That will replace everything after (and including) `_qq` with null.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the new column and update it using the next sentence:

```
select split_part(<string>, '_qq'::text, 1);
```

--EXAMPLE:

```
  select split_part('Cat_old_qq34569er', '_qq'::text, 1);
```

--Result: Cat_old

I hope that this can help you. Greetings.